# How to create confusion matrix for change detection with remote sensing data?

Tags: matlab

If I have output image and ground truth image then how to calculate the confusion matrix of 2X2 dimesion with element TP,TN,FP,FN.

Please tell me any matlab code.

Thank you

Comment: Your question is very broad. Please provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will increase your chances of getting a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your two images are called `output` and `ground_truth` and they are 2-label images (i.e. each pixel is `0` for "no change" or `1` for "change") then you can compute the confusion matrix as

```
>> confusionmat(output(:), ground_truth(:))

ans =

         927        2110
        2155        4808
```

Comment: Thank you so much @ chris taylor